# Implementing custom fonts on an owned remote server does not work

Tags: html, css, import, fonts

I am trying to use fonts on an owned remote server, but it does not load in Mailchimp. Would you take a look at the code and let me know where should I look to solve the problem? thanks

```
<link href="https://.................ttf" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,p { 
   font-family: 'iransans', serif !important; 
   font-weight: 300 !important; 
} 
h1 { 
   line-height:44px !important; 
   color: #111 !important;
} 

</style>
<h1>Testing<br />
Marketing academy</h1>
```

Comment: Note: the `<link>` and `<br>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect method of initializing a font. The correct is

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: 'iransans'; 
    src: url(https://.................ttf) format("truetype");
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,p  { 
    font-family: 'iransans', serif !important; 
}
h1 { 
   line-height:44px !important; 
   color: #111 !important;
} 
</style>
<h1>Testing<br />
Marketing academy</h1>
```

**UPDATED**

Or make a separate document like **iransans.css** with following code (sometimes tag `stile` ignores by mail clients):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'iransans'; 
    src: url(https://.................ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

Then yo can add to your html:

```
<link href="https://yourdomain.com/iransans.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

And them add as a style or a single line:

```
<p style="font-family: ‘iransans’, Arial, sans-serif;">...</p>
```

BUT! If you would like to use custom font in Gmail - you will have to use one only from here https://fonts.google.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although it seems that it solved the problem, but when I use the following code in the body of my email, it ignores "iransans" which is my first font in the font-family and loads the second system font which is tahoma. Would you tell me why this happens?     <p><span style="font-family:iransans,tahoma">testing</span></p>

Comment: Maybe you might add quotes around 'iransans'. <p><span style="font-family:'iransans',tahoma">testing</span></p>. If the answer is correct, don't forget to mark is as accepted.

Comment: And, you should know. Not every email client will support adding a custom font.

Comment: Hi, I added single quotes around 'iransans' but it didn't solve the problem. It seems that it has been ignored by mailchimp.Thanks in advance

Comment: What mail client do you use to receive an email?

Comment: mostly Yahoo & Gmail. and also our domain based webmail client

Comment: Updated an answer for you